# How to fix font face for internet explorer

Tags: css, font-face

I have a social network that allows users to choose fonts for their profiles. It works great on Chrome, Safari and Firefox but IE7-9 does not play well.

What should I change in my font php file to echo some nice css? Here is the code:

```
$fontovi_style='';
foreach(explode(",", str_replace("\n",'',file_get_contents(ROOT.'media/font-list.txt'))) as $k=>$v){
$ime=str_ireplace('.ttf','',$v);
$fontovi_style.='@font-face {font-family:"'.$ime.'";src: url("/media/fonts/'.$v.'") 
format("truetype");}'."\n";
}
echo $fontovi_style;
```

Comment: [IE does not support ttf fonts](http://webfonts.info/browser-support-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support TTF, it only supports EOT.

Check [this link](http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680) for further explanation.

This is to some extent a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323078/css-font-issue-in-internet-explorer)

I'd just like to make an observations though: Generating this list on the fly for every single page slows down page load plus it puts some extra load on your server (ie it's not cacheable, it makes your pages larger, I/O reading the font list every time, etc)

Answer (score -1):

go to this link http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

upload your font

then download all files have different font formats which is supported for different browsers and use in your project. now it will work accurately in all browsers